# SQLAlchemy throwing integrity error, "update or delete on table violates foreign key constraint"

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to set-up a cascade delete on a join relationship. However, whenever I try to delete a post in my application, I receive an error saying that, "update or delete on table "post" violates foreign key constraint" Here is a photo of the error message:

[image: Error Message]

Here is my code:

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    """Blog posts"""

    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                   primary_key=True,
                   autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(25),
                      nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(500),
                        nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,
                           default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    user_table = db.Column(db.Integer, 
                           db.ForeignKey('users.id',
                                         ondelete='CASCADE'))

    tags = db.relationship('Tag', 
                            secondary="post_tags", 
                            back_populates="posts",
                            cascade="all, delete"
                            )


class Tag(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                       primary_key=True,
                       autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String,
                        unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post',
                            secondary="post_tags",
                            back_populates="tags")
    
 

class Post_Tag(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "post_tags"

    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                        db.ForeignKey('posts.id'), primary_key=True)
    
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                        db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Based on the documentation and other questions I've viewed, I seem to be setting this up correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I can delete Tags, but cannot delete Posts

Comment: Include `ondelete="CASCADE"` for `post_tags.post_id`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be recieving this error because you're using `backref` instead of `back_populates`...

***Also, I'd suggest defining your relationship bidirectionally***, meaning in both the parent `Post` and child `Tag` models. This allows cascade deletion to the secondary table with different rules depending on which object is being deleted.

The following changes to your models should fix the error you're receiving:

```py
# Modify your tags relationship to the following:
class Post(db.Model):
    ...
    tags = db.relationship(
               'Tag', 
               secondary="post_tags", 
               back_populates="posts", # use back-populates instead of backref
               cascade="all, delete"
           )


# Also, define your relationship from your tag model
class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship(
               'Post', 
               secondary="post_tags",
               back_populates="tags", # use back-populates instead of backref 
               # When a parent ("post") is deleted, don't delete the tags...
               passive_deletes=True
           )
```

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to have solved the issue for being able to delete tags. However, I am still being thrown the same error when I try to delete a post

Comment: In that case, you'll want to remove `ondelete="CASCADE"` from `post_tags.tag_id` (however, keep for `post_tags.post_id`. @rudehlabya -->